# My $_POST and $_GET dont work

Tags: php, post, get, smarty

I tried doing an `isset($_POST['btnSubmit']`. It gives me nothing so tried to var_dump it. It sais itis empty both before and after i click the button . I even tried to print_r it like this `print_r($_POST['btnSubmit']);`. What it gives me is:

> Undefined index: btnSubmit in

Same thing happens if I use `$_GET`, `$_SESSION` , `$_COOKIE`.

Here is the `.tpl` file:

```
<html lang="sv">
  <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="passwordRetrivalStyle.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="skriptRetrival.js"></script>
  <title>{$title}</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header><img src="arrow-back.svg" alt="arrow-back.svg" onclick="goBackFunction()" id="arrow-back"></header>

  <div id="content">
    <form method="post" action="passwordRetrival.inc.php">
      <center><span id="headText">{$headText}</span><br/><br/></center>

      <center><span id="smallText">{$smallText}</span></center><br/>

      <center><input type="text" name="txtForgot" class="txtForgot" placeholder="Email" />

      <br/><br/><br/>
    </center>


      <center><input type="submit" name="btnSubmit"  value="Retrieve Password" class="forgotSubmit" /></center>
      <center><input type="submit" name="btnDone" value="Ok, got it" class="newButtonFinished" /></center>
      <br/><br/>
      <center><div id="opsMSG"></div></center>
      <center><div id="errorMsg"></div></center>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you need to use `if( isset( $_POST['btnSubmit'] ) ) { print_r($_POST['btnSubmit']); }`  . try it and let me know the status.

Comment: There are two submit buttons, which one are you clicking?

Comment: Try:  print_r($_POST) or echo $_POST['btnSubmit'] see what happens

Comment: i tried if( isset( $_POST['btnSubmit'] ) ) { print_r($_POST['btnSubmit']); } , nothing happends

Comment: As David said, you'll get only the text of the submit button you pressed

Comment: @David I am clicking the "btnSubmit" the one on top

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` and you'll see which elements the POST-array contains. Your form submits to the page passwordRetrival.inc.php (`action="passwordRetrival.inc.php"`) though, so you'll only be able to see it on that page when you click the form.

Comment: @Qirel The user is not suppose to see any other page , the dom just changes with JS. I already tried to var dump it and i  get array (size=0)
  empty